# How can i change the color of a line plot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot some lines and i need each one of them to be a different color for easy identification. I've tried searching but nothing that I found worked, the lines are always black.

Here's what I'm using to plot:

```
reset

set terminal postscript eps enhanced dashed defaultplex "Helvetica" 25

set nokey
#set title "(f)"
set xrange[0:1]
set yrange[0:200]
#set autoscale x
#set autoscale y

#set xlabel'{/Symbol e}' #eixo x
#set ylabel'{/Symbol d}' #eixo y


set cbrange[0:9]
set palette defined (0 "white",\
1.8 "white",1.8 "yellow",2.2 "yellow",2.2 "white",\
2.8 "white",2.8 "green",3.2 "green",3.2 "white",\
3.8 "white",3.8 "pink",4.2 "pink",4.2 "white",\
5.8 "white",5.8 "blue",6.2 "blue",6.2 "white",\
7.8 "white",7.8 "red",8.2 "red",8.2 "white",\
9.0 "white")
set output 'periodosz.eps'
plot 'periodos.dat' using 1:2:3 with image, \
     'return_1_menos.dat' using 1:2 with lines lt 1 lc rgb "red" ,\
     'return_1_mais.dat' using 1:2 with lines lt 1 lc rgb "blue" , \
     'return_2_mais.dat' using 1:2 with lines lt 1 lc rgb "green" , \
     'return_2_menos.dat' using 1:2 with lines lt 1 lc rgb "yellow" ,\
     'return_3_mais.dat' using 1:2 with lines lt 1 lc rgb "pink" , \
     'return_3_menos.dat' using 1:2 with lines lt 1 lc rgb "violet"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the postscript terminal that you want a color output, by adding `color` to your first line:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color dashed defaultplex "Helvetica" 25
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

Just use rgb values instead of naming the colors.

Example : 
Change

`rgb “yellow”`

To

```
rgb "#FFFF00”
```

https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html#color-table is a cool website where you can get all the rgb values that you need

Comment: well, I can't reproduce this. Why should it be in color when you are using `"#FF0000"` instead of `"red"`?
It looks like if you once set the terminal to `color` (as @Vicinius Placco writes) the output is in color. But even if I you later set the terminal _without_ color in the same gnuplot session, the output is _still_ in color. Strange...

Comment: "set term postscript {mono|color}" determines the default sequence of linetype properties.  You can override this by setting a linetype property explicitly, in this case the color.   Note that the postscript terminal was long ago (~30 years!) the first gnuplot terminal with exotic options like color, enhanced text markup, and choice of fonts.  These features were later generalized so that most output modes support them.  For backwards compatibilty with ancient scripts postscript still defaults to monochrome, unlike other terminal types.

Comment: @theozh ah i see, it’s indeed pretty strange how some terminals behave totally differently from others, but what i would do is set the terminal to png and create a png file in my current directory using *set output ‘filename.png’* and then plot all what i need into that file.